# Using Simple Injector with Umbraco Controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, umbraco, simple-injector

I'm trying to Inject a dependency into a controller which inherits from Umbraco's RenderMvcController and getting the error

> No registration for type RenderMvcController could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. For the container to be able to create RenderMvcController it should have only one public constructor: it has 3. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information.

Below is my code to wire up the DI

```
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));



    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICacheProvider, CacheProvider>(Lifestyle.Transient);
        container.Register<ICacheService, CacheService>(Lifestyle.Transient);
    }
```

This is an example of a class receiving the dependency, it inherits from a base class I wrote

```
public class NewsroomController : BaseRenderMvcController
{
    public NewsroomController(ICacheService cacheService) : base(cacheService) { }
```

The base class extends RenderMvcController which is an Umbraco Controller

```
public class BaseRenderMvcController : RenderMvcController
{
    public ICacheService CacheService { get; set; }
    public BaseRenderMvcController(ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        CacheService = cacheService;
    }
}
```

As you can see the base Umbraco controller does in fact have 3 different constructors

```
public class RenderMvcController : UmbracoController, IRenderMvcController, IRenderController, IController
{
    public RenderMvcController();
    public RenderMvcController(UmbracoContext umbracoContext);
    public RenderMvcController(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper);
```

I'm not sure how to get SimpleInjector to place nicely with this controller inherited from Umbraco.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this `RenderMvcController` is a base class and is not intended to be called directly by the user, as in `http://mysite/rendermvc`? Who defined this `RenderMvcController`? You or is it part of another library (such as Umbraco itself)?

Comment: Yeah the RenderMvcController is a controller Umbraco itself provides, it's there to inherited from.

Comment: That's why I made BaseRenderMvcController, just so I can have a base I can control, but my base still has to inherit from RenderMvcController to keep Umbraco happy.

Comment: I can't really imagine that this `RenderMvcController` is defined in an Umbraco assembly, because in that case that controller would not have been registered in the container, since you are simply calling  `RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())`, which simply means that only controllers that are defined in your MVC project are registered. Can you find out in what assembly that `RenderMvcController` lives and what causes it to get registered?

Comment: Hm yeah it's in ```packages\UmbracoCms.Core.7.4.1\lib\umbraco.dll```
That's what I get when I try to inspect RenderMvcController.  
The entire CMS is installed right inside of my main MVC project though.

Comment: Hm there seems to be some detail on
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/using-ioc
"We use a custom MVC controller builder in our code called Umbraco.Web.Mvc.MasterControllerFactory, which needs to always be the default controller factory, if you change this Umbraco will probably not work anymore. The good news is that you can specify 'slave' factories so you can specify custom controller factories for different purposes. "
Unfortunately... I'm not sure I quite understand it how that helps (If it does?)

Comment: @BrooklynWebDevelopers In the same piece of documentation it states: "For the most part, most IoC frameworks will just target setting a custom DependencyResolver which is 100% ok.". Simple Injector does only do that, it doesn't have nor overwrite the ControllerFactory.

Comment: Is there a chnace that you post the complete code for configuring Umbraco with Simple Injector with WebApi included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception message "No registration for type RenderMvcController could be found and an implicit registration could not be made" means that the `RenderMvcController` type is requested directly from Simple Injector, while it hasn't been registered. A controller type is usually only requested by the `DefaultControllerFactory` and it will only request a specific type when it gets a request that has the name of the controller in its url, as in: `http:\\localhost\RenderMvc\3`.

Since you stated in the comments that the `RenderMvcController` is only meant to be used as base controller, I find it suspicious that it is actually requested by MVC. I think you should look into that.

But it the use of this controller is really required, you can simply register it in Simple Injector like this:

```
container.Register<RenderMvcController>(() => new RenderMvcController());
```

There are ways to override Simple Injector's [constructor resolution behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-constructor-resolution-behavior), but I would advise against doing this, because it is an [anti-pattern for components to have multiple constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). It's wise to don't use a container's auto-wiring behavior on framework types (as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Framework-types)), so registering them using a lambda is the advised practice.

Comment: That did fix my problem, though I got an error that it implements IDisposable, so I had to make it
            container.Register<RenderMvcController>(() => new RenderMvcController(), Lifestyle.Scoped);

Comment: Also I considered what you said. Although I have to inherit from the controller to override any custom routes, I imagine Umbaco would use that controller instance for all implicit routes, which is why it was being called up in the first place. 

Thanks so much for your help, and thanks for developing the library in the first place!