# Preventing simple injector from conflicting with Umbraco controllers

Tags: c#, umbraco, simple-injector

Despite only regestering my own mvc controllers in my Umbraco solution, simple injector seems to affect Umbraco's backoffice controllers too. If I run the snippet below, the Umbraco backoffice controllers are getting exceptions, similar to the problems in [this thread](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/78177-simple-injector-framework-registering-webapicontrollers-conflicting-with-cms-apis-not-working).

Do I need to add something like a custom controller activator too?

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    var registeredControllerTypes = 
    SimpleInjectorMvcExtensions.GetControllerTypesToRegister(
        container, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(type => type.IsSubClassOf(typeof(MyController)));

    foreach (var controllerType in registeredControllerTypes)
    {
        container.Register(controllerType, controllerType, Lifestyle.Transient);
    }

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665526/using-simple-injector-with-umbraco-controller

Comment: Probably the solution: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/258

Comment: If this doesn't help, please post the full exception details (stack trace, message, and type of the exception and _all_ inner exceptions).

Comment: @Steven I did some modifications on your suggestions in the thread, since the interface method signature had changed. Is this a valid approach? https://pastebin.com/R9n7z6AR

Comment: Yes, seems legit.

Comment: @Steven Allright, thanks. Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @Steven Yeah, I just wanted to give you the rep :)

Comment: @Steven Can't argue with that. Thanks for the help - I'll post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with an updated version of @Steven's comment:

```
public class UmbracoConstructorBehavior : IConstructorResolutionBehavior
{
    public IConstructorResolutionBehavior DefaultBehavior { get; set; }
    public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type implementationType)
    {
        return implementationType.Namespace != null 
          && implementationType.Namespace.Contains("Umbraco")
            ? GetUmbracoConstructor(implementationType)
            : DefaultBehavior.GetConstructor(implementationType);
    }

    private ConstructorInfo GetUmbracoConstructor(Type i) => 
       i.GetConstructors().OrderBy(c => c.GetParameters().Length).FirstOrDefault() 
       ?? DefaultBehavior.GetConstructor(i);
}
```

Comment: This is what did it for me too