# Custom controller activator for MVC controllers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, umbraco, simple-injector

I would like to know if there is a way to implement a similar solution to [Register subset of Web API controllers with simple injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182026/register-subset-of-web-api-controllers-with-simple-injector), but for MVC controllers rather than web api controllers?

More specifically, it's Umbraco's `RenderMvcController` that I want to register. If I simply use the MVC integration package I get the error described here: [Using Simple Injector with Umbraco Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665526/using-simple-injector-with-umbraco-controller). The proposed solution will hook in to the controllers used by Umbraco's "backoffice" as well. Is there an easy way to leave them intact?

I have tried registering my controllers explicitly, but still get the error mentioned in the thread above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that some views were missing a default controller, which made Umbraco serve a RenderMvcController under the hood. Solved by adding a default controller, which I registered along with my explicit ones:

```
protected override void ApplicationStarting(
    UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver.Current.SetDefaultControllerType(
        typeof(DefaultController));
}
```